# Maxima and Minima of Functions of Two Variables $ f(x,y) = e^{x+y^2}\cdot y $ and $ f(x,y) = e^{x^2-y^2}\cdot y $

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm having trouble finding the local minimum and maximum of the next functions:

$$1.  f(x,y) = e^{x+y^2} \cdot y $$

$ f_x'= (e^{x+y^2}\cdot y)  ; $   $ f_y'= (e^{x+y^2}(1+2y^2)) $

$$ 2. f(x,y) = e^{x^2-y^2}\cdot y $$

$ f_x'= (2xy \cdot e^{x^2+y^2})  ; $   $ f_y'= (e^{x^2+y^2}-y^3 \cdot e^{x^2+y^2}) $

I have found the derivative of $f_x$ and $f_y$. But since I cant find any suspicious min and max for $x$ and $y$ i'm stuck. How i can extract $x$ and $y$ values?

If i had my suspicious points I would put them in Hessian matrix and find the points.

Any help would really appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you have a typo/mistake in the derivative of your second function?  Should it be $\partial f/\partial x  = 2xye^{x^2-y^2}$ ?

Comment: What's the meaning of $f_{x}'?$ Not a standard notation as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Also, have you considered the possibility that there are no local mins or maxes?

Comment: Typographical note: you can use "\cdot" instead of "*" to indicate multiplication (I corrected this in the title).

Comment: If the function is meant to be restricted to some domain set like $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$, you could find that the extrema occur on the boundary of the domain and not at points where the partials vanish.

Comment: fixed the wrong derivatives and the "\cdot".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find extrema, you search for where both the partial derivatives are zero.

As you (almost) wrote, $f_x=e^{x+y^2}\cdot y$. This is zero only if $y=0$. However, $f_y=e^{x+y^2}\cdot (2y^2+1)$ is then non-zero. Therefore there is no critical point for this function, and it has no local minima or maxima on the entire $xy$-plane.

Now do the same kind of analysis on the second function.

Note that you wrote "I can't find any suspicious min and max for $x$ and $y$." But you are not looking for min of $x$ or $y$: you are looking $x$ and $y$ where both partial derivatives are zero. Sometimes such a place does not exist, as in this problem. You should check such a problem with a three-dimensional graphing program or calculator. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimum+of+e%5E%28x%2By%5E2%29*y) is one place for such graphing.

Answer (score 0):

this function has neither a local max nor a local min. But absolute ones -inf and +infinity. Try sketch using mathematica for example.